# Проверка контрольных сумм файлов в ОС Windows

Tags: windows

Как в ОС Windows проверять контрольные суммы файлов? Например, скачиваешь с сайта ISO-образ CD, и проверяешь целостность полученного файла, сравнивая его md5/sha256 хэш с хэшем, опубликованном на сайте.

Хочется максимально интегрированного в "проводник" решения. Не хотелось бы ставить отдельную программу, которую нужно запускать руками для проверки чексуммы.

Comment: Тоже использую стороннее решение - QuickSFV. Удобно, что встраивается в контекстное меню в проводнике.

Comment: Задача проверки хэша возникает не только в связи с проверкой целостности (скачали ISO - проверяем, не побился ли он при загрузке), но и с проверкой соответствия файла тому, который мы собирались получить. Например, существуют вирусы, маскирующиеся под полезное ПО вплоть до полной функциональности изначального ПО, см. http://blogs.cisco.com/security/trojanized-putty-software - выявить такой также можно по контрольной сумме файла-установщика (или `.exe`, если приложение portable, не требующее установки).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть стороннее встраиваемое в "Проводник" решение - [HashCheck Shell Extension](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/). Интегрируется в контекстные меню, умеет хэшировать один файл или все файлы в папке, умеет искать совпадения строки ("скопированного с сайта значения md5 скаченного файла") в любым из поддерживаемых хешей, умеет парсить файлы `*.sfv` и `*.md5` со списком файлов и их хешей, и т.п. Локализовано в том числе на русский язык, совместимо с Windows начиная с XP (заявлено автором), заканчивая 8.1 (проверено мною). Нативно поддерживаются системы x86-32 и x86-64. Open source с BSD-подобной лицензией.

[image: hashcheck]

Есть и решение из коробки - утилита командной строки `CertUtil`. Присутствует в Windows Server 2012 R2 и (некоторых более старых версиях, нужно дополнить информацию). Её основное назначение несколько иное, однако вычислять хэши по алгоритмам MD2 MD4 MD5 SHA1 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512 она умеет. Синтаксис такой:

```
certUtil -hashfile pathToFileToCheck [HashAlgorithm]
```

Например:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>certutil -hashfile ./desktop.ini md5
MD5 hash of file ./desktop.ini:
9e 36 cc 35 37 ee 9e e1 e3 b1 0f a4 e7 61 04 5b
```